# Return a single array individually

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, arraylist, angular6

i want to get the values of the first array for an example on picture array marked 1 in green. How do i do that?

[image]

here's a the array with objects bigger picture

[image]

```js
if (id === 1) {
  this.groupPermissionList.map(p => {
    const permArr = p.permissions;
    console.log(permArr);
  });
}
```

this is how im getting the data from service but now i just want to return a the first list. 2nd list and third individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only log out the array where the `id` is 1 then you'll need to filter the list down first.

```
this.groupPermissionList.filter(p => p.id === 1).map(p => {
    //console.log(p);
    console.log(p.permissions);
});
```

If you only ever expect to match on one item you can use `find` instead.

```
this.groupPermissionList.find(p => p.id === 1).permissions
```

You might want to add an `undefined` check though

```
let group = this.groupPermissionList.find(p => p.id === 1);
if(group) console.log(group.permissions)
```

Comment: i've logged permArr which is the same as p.permissions. i deally i want to return first array only looking at pic marked 1

Comment: Okay, your code you've uploaded is out of date in that case. Also I've edited my answer to filter the collection first.

Comment: i've edited the post. what i want to do is get permArr[0] but this instead returns first object in that array. ideally i should get first array and disregard the other 2

Comment: Could you try applying my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need first to use reduce on the `this.groupPermissionList` to get only the element in the list corresponding to the ID you want, then map on the permissions of it, if I understood what you meant

Comment: No thats not what i meant. i want to separate these 3 arrays into individual arrays so i can get data for first array like permArr[0] but this returns objects an object inside the array